# Meaning of fanning in shear interferometers

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, interference

I recently used a shear interferometer for aligning two lenses in an optical setup (a Galilean beam expander to be precise). I was able to align the lenses such that the vertical stripes were perfectly vertical (i.e. the beam is collimated). But I noticed that the image showed slight fanning:

[image]

With fanning I mean that the stripes seem to be expanding when going to the right. Does anyone know which type of aberration causes this? I'm using [this](https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=2970) shear interferometer:

[image]